# Need help confirming what this line does

Tags: shell, unix

I think I have a pretty good idea of what this line actually does. This line is a part of a system cleanup script that runs throughout the week.

```
DBSBAKDIR=/home/dbtmp/backups
find $DBSBAKDIR -type f -mtime +4 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

From my understanding, does this remove all files in the `/home/dbtmp/backups` directory that are more than 4 days old?

And if I wanted to change logic to remove all files that are more than 2 days old, I would just change the `+4` to `+2`.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @sputnick, please make this an answer so I can award an answer.

Comment: how long did it take you to write this question vs trying it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you expected, the `-mtime` switch is the amount of days `find` will operate on.

So your assumption is good. You can also do more complicated tricks like :

```
find "$DBSBAKDIR" -type f -mtime +4 -mtime -10 -exec echo rm -f {} \;
```

to delete files in a range of days > 4 && < 10

---

To go further, see

[`man find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)